# GO - Is this the proper way to create a multi-output logger?

Tags: go

I needed to write my own lightweight GO multi-output logger for a work project and I've come up with https://github.com/asticode/go-logger.

I'm not here to advertise at all and I'm rather looking for Gopher's opinions (good or bad) on my code and my implementation since I'd like to know whether I've done things right or whether I've gone completely off tracks.

My points of emphasis would be:

- Have I made good use of interfaces?
- Have I made good use of const and global vars ?
- Have I made good use of GO project structure ?
- Have I made good use of GO unit testing package?
- ...

I really thank you in advance for the time you'll put in reviewing my project.

Cheers

Quentin

Comment: Your question does not seem specific enough for SO, maybe it is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @asticode This would be a reasonable Code Review question but make sure to embed the code in the question itself if you do come over.

Comment: You can also ask this over on https://forum.golangbridge.org/

Comment: You're definitely right guys, I've asked my question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110454/go-write-the-perfect-multi-output-logger and I'll be sure to checkout your forum @elithar